# 標準ライブラリ以外のExampleがgodocでは "cannot find package" となり実行出来ない

Tags: go, godoc

godocで実行可能なExampleを表示したくトライしています。
Exampleの表示までは期待通り出来ているのですが、`Play`ボタンをクリックするとplaygroundの出力に`cannot find package`というエラーが出ます。

OS: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
Go: go1.7.4 darwin/amd64

テストコード
$GOPATH/src/hoge/hoge_test.go

```
package hoge_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "hoge"
    "testing"
)

func ExampleHoge() {
    fmt.Println(hoge.Hoge())

    // Output:
    // hoge!!
}
```

テストはPASSします

```
$ go test hoge
ok      hoge    0.011s
```

Godoc

```
$ godoc -play -http=:8080
```

`http://localhost:8080/pkg/hoge/`でドキュメントも想定通り見られて、Exampleもplayground表示されてました。

しかしplaygroundの`Run`をクリックすると、エラーが起きます。

```
tmp/sandbox389904218/main.go:5:2: cannot find package "hoge" in any of:
/usr/local/go/src/hoge (from $GOROOT)
/go/src/hoge (from $GOPATH)
```

見つからないと言われている`hoge`パッケージは今回作成したパッケージです。
今回開発用にGOPATHを設定していますが、上記エラーの`/go`はそのGOPATHに合致していません。

どんな原因が考えられるでしょうか。

#### 補足:

エラーの原因は分かりました。godocのplayable Exampleはplay.golang.orgに処理を委譲(redirect)している様です。つまりエラーメッセージのGOPATHはリモートサーバー上のものでした。

自前パッケージのExample実行方法については未だ不明（そもそも可能なのか？）なので、引き続き質問継続させて下さい。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

私が昔見た頃の godoc はローカルで example が実行出来ていましたが、今コードを見てみると全て play.golang.org に委託する形になっていますね。おそらく雑なサンプルの意味で example を書いている人のテストをローカルで実行してマシンが破壊されたみたいな事が起きない様にするための処置だったのかと思います。
ですので現状の godoc でローカルで example を実行する方法は無いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
そうですか、実行できないんですね・・・残念